# Codeigniter Downlaod Helper not working for Zip files

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, zip, arraybuffer

I am trying to download a file saved in the server and allow the user to extract it from the front end based on the date selected. The application is built using the codeigniter framework.
I am currently using the download helper from codeigniter and it works perfectly when downloading csv files, but the zip file seems to be corrupted always. One thing I notice is that original zip is 101kb in size but the downloaded zip file is 182kb. I have checked the mime type, make sure the output buffer is cleared before sending data but I can't figure out the issue. I would greatly appreciate to hear your opinion.

[image]

**API CALL:**

```
    private function download_get_zip( $year, $month, $day, $type)
    {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
            'Y-m-d H:i:s', "{$year}-{$month}-{$day} 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' )
        );

        $archive_file = implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [
            rtrim( $this->config->item( 'archive_dir' ), '\\/' ),
            $date->format( 'Y' ),
            $date->format( 'm' ),
            $date->format( 'd' ),
            'profiles' . ($type === 'legacy' ? '.csv' : '.zip') 
        ] );

        if( !file_exists( $archive_file ) ) {
            log_message( 'error',
                __METHOD__ . ": Could not find '{$archive_file}'"
            );

            $this->output->set_status_header( 404 );
            return;
        }

        $this->load->helper( 'download' );

        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type' );
        force_download( $archive_file, null, true );
    }
```

**download_helper.php:**

```
    function force_download($filename = '', $data = '', $set_mime = FALSE)
    {
        if ($filename === '' OR $data === '')
        {
            return;
        }
        elseif ($data === NULL)
        {
            if ( ! @is_file($filename) OR ($filesize = @filesize($filename)) === FALSE)
            {
                return;
            }

            $filepath = $filename;
            $filename = explode('/', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $filename));
            $filename = end($filename);
        }
        else
        {
            $filesize = strlen($data);
        }

        // Set the default MIME type to send
        $mime = 'application/octet-stream';

        $x = explode('.', $filename);
        $extension = end($x);

        if ($set_mime === TRUE)
        {
            if (count($x) === 1 OR $extension === '')
            {
                /* If we're going to detect the MIME type,
                 * we'll need a file extension.
                 */
                return;
            }

            // Load the mime types
            $mimes =& get_mimes();

            // Only change the default MIME if we can find one
            if (isset($mimes[$extension])) {
                if ($extension === 'zip') {
                    // Use the second element of the array, which is 'application/zip'
                    $mime = is_array($mimes[$extension]) ? $mimes[$extension][1] : $mimes[$extension];
                } else {
                    $mime = is_array($mimes[$extension]) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
                }
            }
        }

        /* It was reported that browsers on Android 2.1 (and possibly older as well)
         * need to have the filename extension upper-cased in order to be able to
         * download it.
         *
         * Reference: http://digiblog.de/2011/04/19/android-and-the-download-file-headers/
         */
        if (count($x) !== 1 && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/Android\s(1|2\.[01])/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
            $x[count($x) - 1] = strtoupper($extension);
            $filename = implode('.', $x);
        }

        if ($data === NULL && ($fp = @fopen($filepath, 'rb')) === FALSE)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Clean output buffer
        if (ob_get_level() !== 0 && @ob_end_clean() === FALSE)
        {
            @ob_clean();
        }
        // Generate the server headers

        header('Content-Type: '. $mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);
        header('Cache-Control: private, no-transform, no-store, must-revalidate');

        // If we have raw data - just dump it
        if ($data !== NULL)
        {
            exit($data);
        }
        // Flush 1MB chunks of data
        while ( ! feof($fp) && ($data = fread($fp, 1048576)) !== FALSE)
        {
            echo $data;
        }

        fclose($fp);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note: The reason I am using $mimes[$extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bcdi.png) for zip files is because $mimes[$extension][0] translates to x-zip and I wanted to keep the mime as accurate as possible. Additionally, here is the response string I receive as a result of the API call:

[image]

**Frontend Export.js:**

```
    const handleZipExport = type => {
        message.info('Export started')

        menusApi.exportMenus(date).then(
            response => {
                fileDownload(response, `${date}.zip`)
            },
            error => {
                notification.error({ message: 'Error', description: getErrorMessage(error) })
            }
        )
    }
```

The response I get is a binary string I believe and part of me believes that it is the way I am handling data in the frontend that is causing problems since the response seems accurate. In the frontend I am using the fileDownload function from 'js-file-download' library:

```
declare module 'js-file-download' {
    export default function fileDownload(
        data: string | ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | Blob,
        filename: string,
        mime?: string,
        bom?: string
    ): void;
}
```

The original zip file I am trying to download unzips perfectly, contains the contents correctly, but the zip file that is being downloaded is corrupted. I have tried switching browsers to see wether if it was a browser related issue but that didn't seem to help either. Please let me know your opinion, I really appreciate your time.
[image]

Comment: I worked out the solution myself. My suspicion was correct, the issue was related to the way I was processing the data in the frontend. The approach that worked for me was to use xhr to handle the request and convert the information to blob. 

```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the solution myself. My suspicion was correct, the issue was related to the way I was processing the data in the frontend. The approach that worked for me was to use xhr to handle the request and convert the information to blob.

```
    const handleZipExport = type => {
        message.info('Export started')

        const fullURL = `the url where you are requesting zip from`

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('GET', fullURL, true) // Adjust the URL based on your API
        xhr.responseType = 'blob'

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var blob = xhr.response
                fileDownload(blob, `${date}.zip`, 'application/zip')
            } else {
                notification.error({ message: 'Error', description: 'Failed to export zip' })
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            notification.error({ message: 'Error', description: 'Failed to make the zip export request.' })
        }

        xhr.send()
    }
```